# Swapping disks with a higher capacity in a NAS

Tags: raid, nas, synology-diskstation

I have a Synology NAS with 3x 3TB in Raid 1.

One of the disks is in failure mode and the other one is "not happy" (a few smart errors appeared and disappeared).

I am replacing the disk that is failing right now with a 4TB disk.

When I replace the second one, I'll put a 4TB disk as well. How will I be able to expand the capacity to have 4TB usable instead of 3TB at that time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're actually using RAID1 rather than SHR (Synology Hybrid RAID), the array will always be limited to the capacity of the smallest of them. It's because in RAID1 all data is copied across all drives that are part of the array. In a 3TB + 4TB + 4TB configuration the smallest disk couldn't fit the extra 1 TB of data.

SHR takes a different approach: it makes sure that each piece of data has exactly 1 disk of redundancy (or 2 disks in SHR-2). It would slice your 3+4+4 disks into a 3+3+3 part in RAID5 and a 1+1 part in RAID1, giving you 7 GB of total storage and no space wasted.

You can use the [RAID Calculator](https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/RAID_calculator?hdds=3%20TB%7C4%20TB%7C4%20TB) to explore various configurations.

To check which RAID type you're using, open the *Storage Manager*, then *Storage Pool* tab in the left pane. If your storage pool is collapsed, expand it. Look at the *RAID type*.

[image: Screenshot from Storage Manager with RAID type highlighted]

Once you're ready to expand the volume (ie. all disks in RAID1 are now larger/at least 2 disks in SHR are now larger and the array has finished rebuilding), open *Storage Manager* again and switch to the *Volume* tab. Select your volume, click *Action* button on the toolbar and select *Configure*.

[image: Screenshot from Storage Manager with Action - Configure menu item selected]

Finally find *Modify allocated size* label and click *Max*.

[image: Screenshot of the Configure dialog with Max button highlighted]

Comment: it's definitely RAID1, but it's ok to have unused space, I have to replace the other disk quite soon as well, so they'll both eventually have the same capacity again